# unwanted loop in .htaccess

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-redirect

I want to use mod_rewrite to redirect all Urls in http to https except with a single directory.

In other words:

1. Any request for http content will redirected to the content in https
2. Any request for content in the blog directory (URI starting with /blog/) will be redirected to its http equivalent.

I have implemented the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Whenever I call a page with a request URI starting in /blog/ I get a redirect loop. I don't really understand why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is trying to secure only part of your site.  Make the entire thing https-only and be done with it.

Comment: the whole site is in https except few pages where I need to use a pinterest plugin that is not https friendly.

Comment: So fix the plugin.  No, I am not joking.

Comment: it's the official Pinterest board widget. Would love to have it SLL friendly. Unfortunately that is not the case and I have to live with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !blog [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```